# An error occurs when npm run build with Docker

Tags: reactjs, docker, next.js

My simple Docker file in my Next.js project.

And start with this command >> docker build -f Dockerfile -t project-name . & docker build --tag project-name

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbUWd.png)

But an error occurs like this picture when npm run build.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EozL.png)

The important thing is not used "sharp" in my project.

Anyway I rebuild to docker when after install "sharp".

But Also error occurs when npm run install.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzKnd.png)

How can I build in docker Next.js project ?

Comment: Do you have a .Dockerignore file that ignores your local node_modules?

Comment: Sure I did that added node_modules in .dockerignore file.

Comment: Igonre file name must be ".Dockerignore"? My file name is ".dockerignore".

Comment: .dockerignore lowercase is fine, it was a typo on my side!

Comment: Also, I checked my Dockerfiles, the copy statement for the package*.json file is usually without leading slash. COPY package*.json ./. Not sure if it makes a difference, but worth trying!

Comment: Thanks Dom. But same error occurs like first picture

Comment: I think that have to solve "npm WARN deprecated (start with @ dependencies)" when npm install..

Comment: When you run npm run build locally, does it work? Also, could you try it with node 14 (LTS)?

Comment: Local project is build successfully and I trying to build node LTS ver right now.

Comment: Unfortunately build occurred same error

Comment: I have to tried that build from the project of beginning... Thank you for taking your time Dom !!!!